# DataTable doesn't update when the data changes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using datatables plugin to draw tables for my web page. I have a select tag to select buyer with dynamic list of buyers. when i select a buyer it loads respective data of that buyer to the datatable and it works fine. But if i change the buyer the data on the table remains unchanged.

This is the select tag code -

```
<!--=====================================
=            Buyer INPUT           =
======================================-->

                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="input-group">

                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-industry text-aqua"></i></span>

                    <select class="form-control selectBuyer" style="width: 369px" name="selectBuyer" id="selectBuyer" required>

                      <option name="selectBuyer">Select Buyer</option>

                      <?php 

                        $item = null;
                        $value = null;

                        $buyers = ControllerBuyers::ctrShowBuyers($item, $value);

                        foreach ($buyers as $key => $value) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$value["name"].'">'.$value["name"].'</option>';  

                        }

                        echo '</select>';

                      ?>                        

                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 39px"><i class="fa fa-map-marker text-aqua"></i></span>

                    <input class="form-control sAdd" style="width: 370px" type="text" name="sAdd" id="sAdd" readonly required>

                  </div>

                </div>
```

And also the next input tag for address get updated when we select buyer.

this is my javascript code -

```
/*=============================================
ADDING Buyer Address
=============================================*/

$(".piForm").on("change", "select.selectBuyer", function(){

    var name = $(this).val();
    var buyerAddress = $(this).parent().children(".sAdd");  

    var datum = new FormData();
    datum.append("name", name);


    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/buyers.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datum,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(answer){

            $(buyerAddress).val(answer["address"]);

        }

    })

})

/*=============================================
LOAD DYNAMIC PRODUCTS TABLE
=============================================*/
$(".piForm").on("change", "select.selectBuyer", function(){

    var selectedBuyer = $('#selectBuyer').val();

    $('.blocksTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php?selectedBuyer="+selectedBuyer, 
        "deferRender": true,
        "retrieve": true,
        "processing": true
    });

})
```

this is my ajax code -

```
    <?php

require_once "../controllers/mark.controller.php";
require_once "../models/mark.model.php";

class eblocksTablePI{

    /*=============================================
     SHOW Blocks TABLE
    =============================================*/ 

    public function showBlocksTablePI(){        

            $item = null;
            $value = null;

            $answer = ControllerMark::ctrShowMark($item, $value);           

        if(count($answer) == 0){

            $jsonData = '{"data":[]}';

            echo $jsonData;

            return;
        }

        $jsonData = '{

            "data":[';

                foreach ($answer as $key => $value) {

                    if (($value["buyer"] == $_GET["selectedBuyer"]) && ($value["netL"] != 0)) {

                        $blockNo = "$value[blockNo]";

                        $netCUM = "$value[netCUM]";

                        $grossCUM = "$value[grossCUM]";

                        $buttons =  "<button class= 'btn btn-primary addBlock recoverButton' idMark='".$value["id"]."'>Add</button>";

                    $jsonData .='[
                        "'.$blockNo.'",
                        "'.$netCUM.'",
                        "'.$grossCUM.'",
                        "'.$buttons.'"
                    ],';
                }

            }

                $jsonData = substr($jsonData, 0, -1);
                $jsonData .= '] 

            }';

        echo $jsonData;
    }

}


/*=============================================
ACTIVATE PRODUCTS TABLE
=============================================*/ 
$activateBlocksPI = new blocksTablePI();
$activateBlocksPI -> showBlocksTablePI();
```

I have searched but didn't find solutions that are relevant to my problem. the problem is if i select the buyer for the first time the address input gets updated and the blocks table also loads correctly then if i change the buyer the address gets updated but the table remains as is.

Comment: sorry i mistakenly added code which is for edit form. now I've corrected it in the question

Comment: Can you clarify which parts of all this code are not running, and why? If you perform updates using AJAX, is the proper data sent to the backend? Does the answer contain the expected data?

Comment: yes the answer contains updated data when the buyer is changed i have console.logged it and checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are multi-initializing your datatable on click. Put that initialization outside your event handler. And on click, update your data with [`ajax.url()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) and `ajax.load()`.

```
// Initializes
let selectedBuyer = $('#selectBuyer').val();

let myDatatable = $('.blocksTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": "ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php?selectedBuyer="+selectedBuyer, 
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true
});

$(".piForm").on("change", "select.selectBuyer", function(){
    selectedBuyer = $(this).val();

    // Updates on click
    myDatatable.ajax.url("ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php?selectedBuyer=" + selectedBuyer).load();
})
```

Comment: I changed the code but getting error selectedBuyer is not defined.

Comment: Your variable `selectedBuyed` have to be defined before the initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the help I just removed the last part of the ajax url "?selectedBuyer="+selectedBuyer" now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by iArcadia i changed the code in my javascript file which is as below

```
    /*=============================================
LOAD DYNAMIC PRODUCTS TABLE
=============================================*/

let myDatatable = $('.blocksTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php", 
        "deferRender": true,
        "retrieve": true,
        "processing": true
    });

$(".piForm").on("change", "select.selectBuyer", function(){

    var selectedBuyer = $('#selectBuyer').val();

    myDatatable.ajax.url("ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php?selectedBuyer=" + selectedBuyer).load();

})
```

and removed the "?selectedBuyer=" + selectedBuyer" from the ajax url in initialization.
now it is working fine.
Thanks iArcadia for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Previous answer had created 1 more issue which i came to know after testing the code once i re logged in to the website.
The below code is working after multiple tests & relogins

```
    /*=============================================
LOAD DYNAMIC PRODUCTS TABLE
=============================================*/

$(".piForm").on("change", "select.selectBuyer", function(){

    var selectedBuyer = $('#selectBuyer').val();

    let myDatatable = $('.blocksTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php", 
        "deferRender": true,
        "retrieve": true,
        "processing": true
    });

    myDatatable.ajax.url("ajax/datatable-pi.ajax.php?selectedBuyer=" + selectedBuyer).load();   

})
```